# How can I redirect users who are not logged in to my Wordpress site to a special login page?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I setup a redirection on my site on the index.php, but it's really slowing down my site, any suggestion?
Here's my code:

```
<?php 
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) : 

    if ( wp_redirect( '/?page_id=100/' ) ) {
        exit;
    }

endif; 
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="head"></div>
    <main class="main-content">

// code continues
```

Code to redirect visitors to login page

Comment: By redirection being slow, do you mean your login page loads slowly?

Comment: When visiting the site, I believe the time it takes to process if user is logged in or to redirect to login page

Comment: Check the Network tab of browser to see which takes the time: the first page or the redirected page

Answer (score 0):

**edit**

Most likely this is because you are redirecting to a url that is not your login page.  In fact, it can never succeed, because you are basically redirecting it in an endless loop.

index.php will handle requests for /?page_id=100/, so it will just be constantly redirecting to itself.  If you want to do `wp_redirect( '/?page_id=100/')` you will need to make an exception so that it doesn't redirect if you are going to that page.  See the `is_page(100)` conditional below.

---

Best practice for redirecting in Wordpress is to place the redirection as early in the page load cycle as possible.  So I recommend you put the code in your functions.php, not in your index.php.  Put it in the `template_redirect` hook.  At that point you know if the user is logged in or not:

```
function my_page_template_redirect()
{
   if ( !is_user_logged_in() && !is_page(100) {
     wp_redirect( '/?page_id=100/');
   }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_page_template_redirect' );
```

Using this will improve the efficiency of your site because it will check the conditions for redirection before you've wasted time doing a bunch of things that you won't even need to do if you're only going to redirect the user anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I'm getting that the page isn't redirecting properlly "server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete".

Comment: Hmm... try it in template_redirect.  I'll edit my post.  Wait... why do you think that page will have your login on it. Using a "page" for your login is... unlikely to work

Comment: It's the login form displayed on the page. For the 'my_page_template_redirect' I replaced with 'default_template_redirect' could that be an error?

Comment: As long as you rename it the same in both places that won't cause a problem.  I will rewrite the code so that you will be able to redirect to that one page without creating a loop.

Comment: Works!! Thanks for the help, well appreciated.

Comment: Cool.  If you accept and upvote the answer it will help others find useful solutions.

Comment: I did but it's not displayed due to my reputation.

Comment: You should be able to accept the answer, even if you can't upvote it.  Click the grey checkmark just below the upvote arrows.